# Android emulator /dev/kvm not found?

Tags: linux, emulation, android-virtual-device, fedora, kvm

I am using fedora distro.

I went to create android emulator in android studio, but i got that /dev/kvm not found!

I tried to install kvm but still same.

Any one can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable KVM, from the BIOS by pressing F1 key before the system boot. Next, go to the Security tab and enable Intel Virtualization Technology and Intel VT-d Feature. Save the new settings by pressing F10. Finally, exit and restart your computer.